# MySQL Get the last occurence of duplicates rows

Tags: mysql

First I would like to say thank you to everyone that is looking at question and also, say that I really new at SQL in general. Secondly, I hope this is not a duplicate question. I have search a lot and tried a lot, what others were trying to accomplish and have failed.

I trying to getting the last occurrence of a row that would match with the same order number. I have tried group by with a max() on the id and inner joins and so some stuff that was really off the wall.

The few times that I got close is when I would get the highest id, but the rest matched the first occurrence .

```
id | oldValue | newValue | orderNumber
--------------------------------------
1  | 123      | 345      | 12345
2  | 0        | 335      | 12345
3  | 234      | 235      | 34567
4  | 435      | 465      | 45678
5  | 543      | 1235     | 45678
6  | 543      | 578      | 45678
7  | 456      | 23464    | 12222
8  | 233      | 45765    | 14444
9  | 3456     | 6574     | 33345
```

Output to look like.

```
id | oldValue | newValue | orderNumber
--------------------------------------
2  | 0        | 335      | 12345
3  | 234      | 235      | 34567
6  | 543      | 578      | 45678
7  | 456      | 23464    | 12222
8  | 233      | 45765    | 14444
9  | 3456     | 6574     | 33345
```

I don't want to delete any information. I saw that was a very popular choice, to the somewhat same type of problem I'm having. I need to keep all the date.

Any thoughts on how to go about this is greatly appreciated or a resource where I can do some more research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem can be solved with a simple query:

```
select t.* 
from your_table t
join(
   select 
      max(id) as id
   from your_table
   group by orderNumber
) x on x.id = t.id
```

Inner subquery returns only max ids for each orderNumber.

Comment: Oh, I see now. I was doing something like that, but I was doing max() on the outside query. Thanks for the quick reply. I will try it out very soon.